# Conflicting types for 'memchr'

Tags: c++, c, c++builder, c-strings, c++builder-xe6

I'm currently trying to modify a library (ASN.1 Compiler), written in C, so I can compile and use it in C++ Builder (XE6).
Doing that, I've encountered the error "Conflicting types for 'memchr'" (in cstring).

After some research, it seems that this problem comes from the fact that C and C++ code are mixed. However, I can't use the solutions suggested by the article in which I read that since they are related to the GCC compiler, when I'm using C++ Builder and its compilers.

What can be the solutions to solve this error?

Thank you

Comment: Please show the line of code that triggers the error, and the declaration of any variables that are involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mix including `cstring` and `string.h`. Do not do this.

The former declares:

```
void * memchr(void *, int, size_t);
```

the latter does

```
void * memchr(const void *, int, size_t);
```

Those are not of the same type.

Comment: Sorry for commenting late, I thought I couldn't because the topic is "on hold". Thank you for your answer, I already tried not to mix these two includes, without success, but I probably missed some of them. I've reorganised my code and for now I don't have this problem anymore. Have a nice day.

Comment: It should be OK to mix those two headers, you'd just get both versions of `memchr`. Would be nice to see a MCVE here.